# Do expander graphs have the property that with high probability an s-t cut is size min{degree(s),degree(t)}?

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, expanders, max-flow-min-cut

If we want a specific example, then how about the Erdos-Renyi random graph?

Comment: "Expander graphs" is not a class of random objects; they can be constructed deterministically.

Comment: Can you suggest a refinement of the question? What about Erdos-Renyi graphs? Is there a common random class of graphs known to be expanders for which this is not true with high probability?